# Cannot checkout from svn using Jenkins on Docker with Host Mounted Volume

Tags: docker, jenkins, mounted-volumes

I am working with Jenkins Jenkins 2.319.1 on Docker for Windows version 4.2.0.

Running Jenkins as..
docker run --name jenkins -v d:\JenkinsData\jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -dit --restart always jenkins/jenkins:lts

While creating a new project in Jenkins on checkout from repo I get following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to update http://192.168.1.9/svn/ProjectBA/code/Tags/0.3.5.4
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E204899: Cannot rename file '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Project/.svn/tmp/entries' to '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Project/.svn/entries'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:760)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:340)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:910)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:363)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1361)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:859)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.update(SVNUpdateClient16.java:507)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient16.java:364)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient16.java:274)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldUpdate.run(SvnOldUpdate.java:27)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldUpdate.run(SvnOldUpdate.java:11)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:311)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:291)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:387)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:159)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1064)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1040)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1013)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1171)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1154)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:960)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:883)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1213)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:637)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:509)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
    at hudson.matrix.MatrixBuild.run(MatrixBuild.java:323)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:432)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E204899: Cannot rename file '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Project/.svn/tmp/entries' to '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Project/.svn/entries'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNFileUtil.rename(SVNFileUtil.java:784)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminArea14.saveEntries(SVNAdminArea14.java:635)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminArea.modifyEntry(SVNAdminArea.java:866)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNUpdateEditor15.openRoot(SVNUpdateEditor15.java:135)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCancellableEditor.openRoot(SVNCancellableEditor.java:60)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.handlers.DAVEditorHandler.startElement(DAVEditorHandler.java:303)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.handlers.BasicDAVHandler.startElement(BasicDAVHandler.java:89)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:510)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2710)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:898)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:863)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:220)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:451)
    ... 35 more
ERROR: Subversion update failed
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E204899: Cannot rename file '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Project/.svn/tmp/entries' to '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Project/.svn/entries'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNFileUtil.rename(SVNFileUtil.java:784)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminArea14.saveEntries(SVNAdminArea14.java:635)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminArea.modifyEntry(SVNAdminArea.java:866)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNUpdateEditor15.openRoot(SVNUpdateEditor15.java:135)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCancellableEditor.openRoot(SVNCancellableEditor.java:60)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.handlers.DAVEditorHandler.startElement(DAVEditorHandler.java:303)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.handlers.BasicDAVHandler.startElement(BasicDAVHandler.java:89)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:510)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2710)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:898)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:863)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:220)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:451)
Caused: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E204899: Cannot rename file '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Project/.svn/tmp/entries' to '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Project/.svn/entries'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:760)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:340)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:910)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:363)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1361)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:859)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.update(SVNUpdateClient16.java:507)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient16.java:364)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient16.java:274)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldUpdate.run(SvnOldUpdate.java:27)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldUpdate.run(SvnOldUpdate.java:11)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:311)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:291)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:387)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:159)
Caused: hudson.scm.subversion.UpdaterException: failed to perform svn update
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:214)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1064)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1040)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1013)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1171)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1154)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:960)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:883)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1213)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:637)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:509)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
    at hudson.matrix.MatrixBuild.run(MatrixBuild.java:323)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:432)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Seems like this issue is related to permission however I am unable to figure out how to resolve this. Pls advise.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Project type in Jenkins from Multi-configuration Project to Freestyle Project and it started working.

I noticed that in Multi-Configuration Project the workspace directory is located under jenkins_home but for freestyle project the workspace directory is created under the specified build directory that I have created separately.

For me it resolved by just changing Project type in Jenkins.